# Spin of electrons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, quantum-spin

Do electrons possess spin quantum number only in a central potential or can they have spin in other cases also?

Specifically, can two electrons be distinguished based on their spin if they are in a box with infinite potential at the boundaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electrons always have spin quantum number $s=\frac{1}{2}$, and all electrons are indistinguishable, and since they are fermions, an $N$ electron wave function must be antisymmetric under interchange of any two electrons.

Regarding 2 electrons in a box, the eigenstates of total spin are the singlet and triplet states. The singlet state ($S=0, S_z=0)$ is antisymmetric:

$$ |0,0\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}[\uparrow_1\downarrow_2 - \downarrow_2\uparrow_1] $$

The antisymmetric part arises from the fact that swapping particle subscripts $(1, 2)\rightarrow(2,1)$ flips the sign of the spin wave function.

Moreover, the statement that the electrons have opposite spin is somewhat of a classical view--their is one spin up electron and it is 50% particle 1 and 50% particle 2, likewise for the one spin down electron.

Note that that statement also applies to the $S_z=0$ triplet state:

$$ |1,0\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}[\uparrow_1\downarrow_2 + \downarrow_2\uparrow_1] $$

which differs by a sign (so it is symmetric under particle interchange).

Regarding a particle in a box, the eigenstates are:

$$ \psi_n(x) \propto \sin{\frac{n\pi}{L}(x+\frac L 2)}$$

Note that $\psi_n(x)$ is even (odd) for odd (even) $n$.

The two particle spatial wave functions are:

$$ \psi_{n,m}^{\pm}(x_1, x_2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}[\psi_n(x_1)\psi_m(x_2) \pm \psi_n(x_2)\psi_m(x_2)]  $$

where $\psi^+$ ($\psi^-$) is (anti)symmetric, and must be combined with the triplet (singlet) spin state to make the total wave function antisymmetric.

For *any* degenerate state, $n=m$:

$$\psi^-_{n,n}(x_1, x_2) = 0$$

so there is no triplet state, while the spin singlet state combines with

$$\psi^+_{n,n}(x_1, x_2) = \sqrt{2}\psi_n(x_1)\psi_n(x_2) $$

to make an antisymmetric state.

Note that this hold for any $n$, regardless of the parity of the single particle wave function. This can be contrasted with 2 particles in a mutual central potential were the center-of-mass coordinate:

$$ x_{CM} = x_1 + x_2 $$

is ignored, and the problem is cast in a single variable:

$$ x = x_2 - x_1 $$

In this case particle interchange is equivalent to a parity operation:

$$ x = x_2 - x_1 \rightarrow x_1 - x_2 = -x $$

so that the spatial parity of the wave function matters--not because of parity per see, rather because it is the same as particle interchange.

Comment: Thank you, my specific question was can two electrons have the same energy eigenvalue in a 1-D box. Say can two electrons be in n=1 state?

Comment: @TejasP The distinction between a central potential and infinite square well is a good question, though it is not entirely clear that that was the central point of your question. I will edit my answer to address that difference.

Answer (score 1):

Electrons, being *indistinguishable fermions* (in particular, charged leptons), always have spin $1/2$. So, if you put two electrons in a box, *you can't tell which is which*, because all electrons are utterly equal and there's no such thing as "this" or "that" electron.